# Is there any way to create url from dictionary?

Tags: python, urllib

I have a dictionary how do I create url using urllib in python?

```
url_dict = {'scheme': 'https', 'netloc': 'example.com', 'path': '/default.jpg'}
```

I want the below url as returned string.

```
   https://example.com/default.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be a bit more generic, fetching all supported fields:

```
from urllib import urlunparse, ParseResult
url = urlunparse(url_dict.get(f, '') for f in ParseResult._fields)
```

The attribute `ParseResult._fields` despite its `_`-prefixed, is [officially supported](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields), because `ParsedResult` is a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 2):

look at urllib ( `urllib.parse.urlunparse(parts)` ) or just use string formatting

```
url = "%(scheme)s://%(netloc)s%(path)s" % url_dict
```

With urllib it would be something like

```
url = urllib.parse.urlunparse((
    url_dict["scheme"], 
    url_dict["netloc"], url_dict["path"], '', '', ''))
```

Comment: I need to use urllib function becauase of some dynamic issue.

Comment: e detailed out the usage of urlunparse, though I don't understandf what you mean with **dynamic issue**?